# Can angular expressions render XML node attributes , despite [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The code is using the `ng-repeat` directive in an attempt to render an untreated array of XML nodes. Below is one such node.

`<item xmlns="jabber:iq:roster" subscription="none" name="admin" jid="admin@google.io"/>`

I would like to render only the `jid` attribute using ng repeat. I'm aware I could transform the XML node array, but thought and thought could discuss that or alternatives.

`<li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.attr('jid') }}</li>`

Comment: I'd bet user.attr returns a DOM node instead of a plain value/object.

Comment: @JeffHubbard I wouldn't expect that. Usually attr vallues are returned and treated as strings when using Zepto or a Jquery like lib.

Comment: @JeffHubbard and in this case nothing is being returned because AngularJS restricts access to DOM nodes from within expressions since it's a known way to execute arbitrary Javascript code. Just wondering if there is a directive to aid with this

Comment: What library are you actually using to parse this XML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user._jid }}</li>
```